# How can you render everything behind a 2d square/plane except for a specific sprite in a 2d game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a problem where I'm trying to make a square appear in the scene that renders the background behind it yet not render or show a specific object that appears in between the background and that square.

Comment: Please add more details and pictures/drawings depicting what you wish to accomplish ...along with the steps that you've taken to achieve these goals. Some steps that you might want to look into are setting Enabled to false, turning off the renderer for objects, using tags to filter objects rendered, using the z-index/position in the hierarchy  etc...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution for your problem is use the component "Sprite Mask".

Here you got the link to the documentation of this component where explain how it works. You can also found a lot of examples on youtube about this topic

[Sprite Mask Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html)

Comment: Ah it was so obvious all along. Thank you!!!.